# Is it possible to create dynamic reference line in waterfall chart or Funnel chart in Einstein Analytics?

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

[image: I want a dynamic reference line(suppose 3M) based on a query.]

I have tried to find adding reference line options under widget section. Not able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not.
I just tried to add a reference line manually in the json code. It doesn't crash or show an error, but it simply doesn't show a line.